# Multiple screens but self.root.ids retuns an error

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivymd

This code actually worked until I added multiple screens.  It still works when I remove the multi Screen Manager. I get the attrubite error point to `Chapter ids`
Im trying to add a chapters screen. What Im I doing wrong please.

I think the error is from self.root.ids. I may be wrong. Below is thwe code

Python

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.list import OneLineListItem
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivymd.uix.button import MDRectangleFlatIconButton, MDFloatingActionButton
from kivy.lang import Builder
import pygame

pygame.mixer.init()
path = "C://abapp3"


class BooksScreen(Screen):
    pass


class ChapterScreen(Screen):
    pass


class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(BooksScreen(name='BooksScreen1'))
        sm.add_widget(ChapterScreen(name='ChapterScreen1'))

    return sm

def on_start(self):
    songs = self.load_songs(path)
    pygame.mixer.music.load(songs[0])

def load_songs(self, path_):
    songs = []
    for filename in os.listdir(path_):
        if filename.endswith('.wav'):
            songs.append(os.path.join(path_, filename))
            self.root.ids.Chapter.add_widget(OneLineListItem(text=filename[2:],
                                                         on_release=self.play_song,
                                                         pos_hint={"center_x": 1, "center_y": 1}, ))

    return songs

@staticmethod
def play_song(*args):
    pygame.mixer.music.play()
    print(OneLineListItem.text)

@staticmethod
def stop_song(*args):
    pygame.mixer.music.stop()
    print("song stopped")
```

MainApp().run()

.KV

```
ScreenManager:
    Screen
        BooksScreen:
        ChapterScreen:



<BooksScreen>:
    NavigationLayout:
        ScreenManager:
            Screen:
                # Front / Main Screen
                MDBoxLayout:
                    orientation: "vertical"
                   #Toolbar
                    MDToolbar:
                        title: "Chapters"
                        font_style: "Caption"
                        elevation: 8
                        left_action_items: [['menu', lambda x: nav_drawer.set_state("open")]]

                    Widget:

                #stop/pause Button
                MDBoxLayout:
                    orientation:"vertical"
                #    id: StopButton
                    text:"Pause"

                BoxLayout:
                    Button:
                        text: 'Goto settings'
                        on_press:
                            root.manager.transition.direction = 'left'
                            root.manager.current = 'ChapterScreen1'





                # Chapters list/ Play list
                MDScreen
                    MDBoxLayout:
                        orientation: "vertical"
                        MDList
                            id: Chapter



        #Options menu
        MDNavigationDrawer:
            id: nav_drawer
            MDBoxLayout:
                orientation: "vertical"
                padding: "8dp"
                spacing: "8dp"




                ScrollView:
                    # Options Menu Options
                    MDList:
                        MDRectangleFlatIconButton:
                            on_press:
                                root.ids.nav_drawer.set_state("close")

                            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
                            icon: 'arrow-left'
                            line_color: 0, 0, 0, 0




                        OneLineIconListItem:
                            text: "Options"
                            font_style: "Caption"
                            #size_hint_y: None
                            #height: self.texture_size[1]

                         # Options Menu- About
                        OneLineIconListItem:
                            text: "About"
                            font_style: "Caption"
                           # size_hint_y: None
                            #height: self.texture_size[1]

                        # Options Menu Storage
                        OneLineIconListItem
                            text: 'Storage'
                            font_style: "Caption"
                            #IconLeftWidget
                                #icon: 'tools'

                        # Options Menu Toolbox
                        OneLineIconListItem:
                            text: 'Choose Voice'
                            font_style: "Caption"

                            #IconLeftWidget:
                            #    icon: 'toolbox'

                        # Options Menu About
                        OneLineIconListItem:
                            text: 'About'
                            font_style: "Caption"
                           # IconLeftWidget:
                            #    icon: 'toolbox-outline'
<ChapterScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text: 'Back to menu'
            on_press:
                root.manager.transition.direction = 'right'
                root.manager.current = 'BooksScreen1'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line:

```
        self.root.ids.Chapter.add_widget(OneLineListItem(text=filename[2:],
                                                     on_release=self.play_song,
                                                     pos_hint={"center_x": 1, "center_y": 1}, ))
```

is trying to reference the `Chapter` `id` as if it were a member of the `ScreenManager` (`root`) `ids`, but it is not. It is a member of the `ids` of the `BookScreen`. You can fix that error by referencing the `BookScreen` instance in the problem line using the `get_screen()` method of `ScreenManager`:

```
        self.root.get_screen('BooksScreen1').ids.Chapter.add_widget(OneLineListItem(text=filename[2:],
                                                     on_release=self.play_song,
                                                     pos_hint={"center_x": 1, "center_y": 1}, ))
```