# Binding of on_release to OneLineIconListItem in KivyMD

Tags: python, kivymd

I am trying to modify a KivyMD OneLineIconListItem example from https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/themes/icon-definitions/ that does the autocomplete search that I've been trying to figure out for a current project.

TODO: Add on_release to item to print item and add to list

[Bind on_release in Kivy List item to function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66507225/bind-on-release-in-kivy-list-item-to-function/66508257#66508257) is the closest that I've found to do what I want, but I'm having trouble adapting it.

Here is what I have so far:

```py
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.icon_definitions import md_icons
from kivymd.uix.list import OneLineIconListItem

Builder.load_string(
'''
#:import images_path kivymd.images_path


<CustomOneLineIconListItem>
    on_release: root.print_item

    IconLeftWidget:
        icon: root.icon


<PreviousMDIcons>

    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        spacing: dp(10)
        padding: dp(20)

        MDBoxLayout:
            adaptive_height: True

            MDIconButton:
                icon: 'magnify'

            MDTextField:
                id: search_field
                hint_text: 'Search icon'
                on_text: root.set_list_md_icons(self.text, True)

        RecycleView:
            id: rv
            key_viewclass: 'viewclass'
            key_size: 'height'

            RecycleBoxLayout:
                padding: dp(10)
                default_size: None, dp(48)
                default_size_hint: 1, None
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.minimum_height
                orientation: 'vertical'
'''
)


class CustomOneLineIconListItem(OneLineIconListItem):
    def print_item(self, instance):
        print(instance, instance.text)
    icon = StringProperty()


class PreviousMDIcons(Screen):

    def set_list_md_icons(self, text="", search=False):
        """Builds a list of icons for the screen MDIcons."""

        def add_icon_item(name_icon):
            self.ids.rv.data.append(
                {
                    "viewclass": "CustomOneLineIconListItem",
                    "icon": name_icon,
                    "text": name_icon,
                    "callback": lambda x: x,
                }
            )

        self.ids.rv.data = []
        for name_icon in md_icons.keys():
            if search:
                if text in name_icon:
                    add_icon_item(name_icon)
            else:
                add_icon_item(name_icon)


class MainApp(MDApp):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.screen = PreviousMDIcons()

    def build(self):
        return self.screen

    def on_start(self):
        self.screen.set_list_md_icons()



MainApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is just replacing

```py
<CustomOneLineIconListItem>
    on_release: root.print_item
```

with,

```py
<CustomOneLineIconListItem>
    on_release: root.print_item(self) # Call the method by passing this instance.
```

Comment: Thanks @ApuCoder  I knew it had to be simple, but it just wasn't clicking.